# Casting Struct to unsigned char * for IPC needs

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct _message
{

    int mode;
    char system[25];
    ...

}message;
```

I would like to send this across to another process via domain sockets :

```
message msg;

//populate msg
....

unsigned char * data = &msg;

//allocate IPC buffer

unsigned char * ipc_buffer;
ipc_buffer = get_ipc_buffer(sizeof(message));

//Copy
memcpy(ipc_buffer,data,sizeof(message));

//Send

send_ipc_msg(ipc_buffer,sizeof(message);

//At the receving end

recv_ipc_msg(ipc_rcv_buffer,sizeof(ipc_rcv_buffer));

ipc_message* data = (message*)ipc_rcv_buffer;

//Access members

data->mode;
```

I think it is OK to just cast the struct to (unsigned/signed char*) copy it to a IPC buffer and send it over UDP domain socket since it is sent within given platform. Or Should I still be worried about the alignment issues and struct packing with the above mentioned way of direct casting and not using serailization?

Comment: You need to worry about the alignment of `ipc_rcv_buffer`. Using `malloc` to allocate the buffer should guarantee proper alignment.

Comment: @user3386109 Can you eloborate? Yes, I do use malloc in `get_ipc_buffer`.

Comment: And you do need to worry about structure packing. If you are going to pass the struct across process boundaries without serialization, you should pack the structure to a 1-byte alignment to remove any padding between the data members.

Comment: The concern is at the receiving end. If you declare `ipc_rcv_buffer` as an array of `char` (local, global, or static), then there's no guarantee that it will properly aligned to be cast to a `(message *)`.

Comment: Additionally, you need to worry about "byte ordering"... Your sender should use htonl/htons as appropriate, and the receiver should use ntohl/ntohs as appropriate.

Comment: @Remy,  please correct me here if wrong  - the two programs have the same defnition of struct and are compiled to be run on the same system. Still packing will tend to make a difference?

Comment: @TonyB if the two processes are on the same machine, byte ordering is not a big issue. It is when data crosses machine boundaries that byte order becomes a concern.

Comment: @Prabhu yes, packing is still a concern. Even if the two programs run on the same system, they may have been compiled with different alignment settings. If the code is not *explicit* about the structure alignment using `#pragma` or equivilent, the alignment will be subject to compiler configuration, which can differ between projects and effect the same definition in different ways.

Comment: Formal stuff: 1.) This `send_ipc_msg(ipc_buffer,sizeof(message);` misses a closing parenthesis. 2.) What is `ipc_message`? 3.) You do not (and even cannot) *cast a `struct` to a pointer*. What you do is casting a `strcut`'s *address* to a pointer.

Comment: @alk, thanks for the correction. `ipc_message` should be `message`. Typo there. And yes, get your point on casting a struct's address. I framed  the question incorrectly.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - That is correct that byte ordering is not an issue when both processes are on the same host, however given the minimal effort in ensuring correct byte order handling, I always add it... that way if the program usage changes to be between hosts, no change to the code is necessary.